# Insert enter marks before the selected word

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-unicode

I need to insert line breaks (enter marks) between a string before each new word starts.

String:

```
test (n) trial, experiment, check run (v) race, rush speed (n) race, sprint, rush, dash, zoom
```

Expected:

```
test (n) trial, experiment, check 
run (v) race, rush 
speed (n) race, sprint, rush, dash, zoom
```

This regular expression selects the word before paranthesis. But how do I insert an enter mark at the right place?

> \w+(?=\s+((.*?)))

---

Update:

The answer do not apply to the actual string that I need to process. Does unicode strings treated differently by regular expression?

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+)(?= (?:[()])).*?"

test_str = "खत (स्त्री) पाहा : भेट मुलगा (पु) पोर‚ पोरगा‚ पोरटा‚  कारटा‚ किशोर‚ कुमार‚ कुमारिका‚ तरुण; लग्नाचा/उपवधू मुलगा; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष (n) boy, lad, kid, urchin; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष मुलगी (स्त्री) पोर‚ पोरगी‚ पोरटी‚ बाला‚ बाळा‚ बालिका‚ छोकरी‚ छोटी‚ बेटी‚ कारटी‚ नग्निका‚"

subst = "\\n\\1"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str , 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

The first line break is correct "\nखत" but the second one is incorrect at "पुरु\nष ". Third and forth are missing.

Expected:

```
खत (स्त्री) पाहा : भेट 
मुलगा (पु) पोर‚ पोरगा‚ पोरटा‚  कारटा‚ किशोर‚ कुमार‚ कुमारिका‚ तरुण; लग्नाचा/उपवधू मुलगा; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ 
पुरुष (n) boy, lad, kid, urchin; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष 
मुलगी (स्त्री) पोर‚ पोरगी‚ पोरटी‚ बाला‚ बाळा‚ बालिका‚ छोकरी‚ छोटी‚ बेटी‚ कारटी‚ नग्निका‚
```

Comment: Please explain how are you identifying a new word?

Comment: the word before paranthesis is a new word

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/dXfQsC/1) help?

Comment: Updated my question with unicode string example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
\s+([^(\s]+\s+(?=\(.*?\)))
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXfQsC/9)

---

- `\s+` - A whitespace character, one or more times. To prevent trailing spaces later on.
- `(` - Opening 1st capturing group.
- `[^(\s]+` - Negated character class: No opening paranthesis or whitespace character, one or more times.
- `\s+` - A whitespace character, one or more times.
- `(?=\(.*?\))`- Positive lookahead for literal opening paranthesis, any character other than newline zero or more times (lazy) and a literal closing paranthesis.
- `)` - Closing 1st capturing group.

---

As an alternative maybe try to use `regex` module instead of `re` and try this pattern:

```
((?<=\s+)[\p{Devanagari}\p{L}]+(?=\s*\(.*))
```

---

- `\s+(` - One or more spaces and Opening 1st capture group. This to prevent trailing spaces once we put newlines later on.
- `(?<=\s+)` - Positive lookbehind for a whitespace character (to prevent start string).
- `[\p{Devanagari}\p{L}]+` - Character class for any one or more Devanagari or any kind of letter from any language.
- `(?=\s*\(.*)` - Positive lookahead for a literal opening paranthesis, zero or more characters except newline.
- `)` - Close 1st capture group.

---

Python Code:

```
import regex
test_str = "खत (स्त्री) पाहा : भेट मुलगा (पु) पोर‚ पोरगा‚ पोरटा‚  कारटा‚ किशोर‚ कुमार‚ कुमारिका‚ तरुण; लग्नाचा/उपवधू मुलगा; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष (n) boy, lad, kid, urchin; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष मुलगी (स्त्री) पोर‚ पोरगी‚ पोरटी‚ बाला‚ बाळा‚ बालिका‚ छोकरी‚ छोटी‚ बेटी‚ कारटी‚ नग्निका‚"
str_new = regex.sub(r'\s+((?<=\s+)[\p{Devanagari}\p{L}]+(?=\s*\(.*))', r'\n\1', test_str)

print(str_new)
```

Prints:

```
खत (स्त्री) पाहा : भेट
मुलगा (पु) पोर‚ पोरगा‚ पोरटा‚  कारटा‚ किशोर‚ कुमार‚ कुमारिका‚ तरुण; लग्नाचा/उपवधू मुलगा; पाहा : पुत्र ‚
पुरुष (n) boy, lad, kid, urchin; पाहा : पुत्र ‚ पुरुष
मुलगी (स्त्री) पोर‚ पोरगी‚ पोरटी‚ बाला‚ बाळा‚ बालिका‚ छोकरी‚ छोटी‚ बेटी‚ कारटी‚ नग्निका‚
```

[Python Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AjarStridentDemos)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex-replace statement that does that:

```
text = "test (n) trial, experiment, check run (v) race, rush speed (n) race, sprint, rush, dash, zoom"

re.sub(r"(\w+ \(\w\))", r"\n\1", text)
```

Output:

```
'\ntest (n) trial, experiment, check \nrun (v) race, rush \nspeed (n) race, sprint, rush, dash, zoom'
```

When printed, it provides:

```
test (n) trial, experiment, check 
run (v) race, rush 
speed (n) race, sprint, rush, dash, zoom
```